# React Native: How to disable swipe gesture only for ScrollView but content should scroll left and right only with button controller?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need some help. So scenario is that I am using `ScrollView` component in react native whose props have `horizontal` for horizontal scrolling. And I have two button  whose purpose is to control to scroll to next card and previous card. Now I want to disable swipe gesture only for `ScrollView`. User should/could not scroll content with swipe gesture but they can only scroll with help of button only. As I try using `ScrollView`'s available props as well which is `scrollEnabled={false}`. But It will helps me to stop swipe gesture but also button controller to scroll is stop working. Here is my method for button controller.

```
const scrollToNextInfo = () => {
  if (scrollViewRef) {
    scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollTo({
    x: selectScreenWidth + widthOfCard,
    y: 0,
    animated: true,
    });
  }
};
```

And `ScrollView` Component Looks as:

```
<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  // scrollEnabled={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
>
   // Card Component with width as widthOfCard          
</ScrollView>
{/** Button Controller Component **/}
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.previousButton}
      onPress={scrollToNextInfo} 
    >
      <LeftIcon />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Hoping for positive response. Thank you in advance. :)